# Most common way to exchange data between C++ application and webserver interface

Tags: c++, linux, interface

Consider the following scenario:

A linux-based system runs a C++ application. The system requires a user name and a password and is only accessable by using a web browser:

[image]

What is the best way to exchange data between the webserver and the C++ application? Fictional examples:

- The webserver should show to the user how many devices are currently working with the C++-program as a list
- Contrary the user might change a specific setting for the C++-program, e.g. changing an application related port number

What is the most common approach to achieve this configurational data exchange? Using *.xml-files as some kind of interface?

Comment: I think most simple way is to embed a web server inside C++ application =)

Comment: I am not sure about this. I tried avoiding coding my own web server which is included within the application. Maybe there is something similar to this servlet/java stuff?

Comment: Define *best*. Anyway, you can use any kind of IPC you like. For extreme efficienty, you could even code your main program/the connector as a module of the web-server.

Comment: Explain what is your C++ application? Is it a long-running process, or a server? Does it on the contrary compute stuff fairly quickly (in a fraction of a second)? Do you want to have a lot of simultaneous web users (e.g. thousands of browsers connection to your dynamic website at the same time) or only a few of them?

Comment: It is a long-running process and computes stuff fairly quickly. Remote access is for setting parameters only (maintenance). I dont understand why my question is being voted down by several users. Yes, it is a general question since I am searching for a general design approach (key words to search for etc.). Thanks to harmic and basile for providing some ideas/approaches

Comment: Since my question has been closed please pay attention to my previous comment. I do not think that my question is too broad since it was about evaluating design approaches related to this application field.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a daemon, which you want to provide a web interface to, and you do not want to embed a web server directly in it, or embed it in a web server, then you need an IPC mechanism.

Linux provides plenty of primitives for this, of which the most commonly used in this situation is sockets. The C++ program would listen on the socket, waiting for connections from the webserver. The webserver would connect to the socket, send requests, and the program would respond.

[Here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) is quite a nice tutorial on this, written for C but applicable to C++.

Often rather than directly using the primitives, one would use a framework. A quick Google search revealed [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) which looks suitable. But there are a lot of alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [evilruff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2164788/evilruff)'s comment: the simplest way is probably to embed a web server inside your application. This is actually quite simple. You could use [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) for that.

If you insist on having a separate Apache webserver, consider either the old [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) way, or better yet, a [Fastcgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) approach.

You might consider also having your C++ application put some data in a database (e.g. PostgresQL) and have another Web application query that database. I'm not sure it is a good way to solve your issue.

In general, it looks like you want some [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) or some [remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). There are lots of alternatives: [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), [ONC/RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONC_RPC), [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) etc etc.